# How can I add old data to a newly created metric on GCP stackdriver?

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to create a new metric on Stackdriver and then check all the data before the metric was created based on it. Right now charts are showing only the new data. Is it possible?

E.g. I want to create a metric for API requests and then want to analyze the data based on labels I add. Right now I can do it only with the requests which are made after the metric creation, however I need the historical data too.

Answer (score 3):

Stackdriver Logging does not backfill the metric from previous log entries. This is current limitation. You can find details [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/#troubleshooting).

Comment: Thanks, that's unfortunate. I saw this in the docs but was curious if anyone managed to find a solution.

Most likely this could be a reason to go with another tool.